# Misunderstood question or is it really badly written?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

I got [one of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910743/hiding-a-div-after-a-file-is-downloaded) put on hold and I'm wondering how I could've wrote my question better.

I explained that the previous behavior used window.onfocus to hide a div after a file was downloaded. This doesn't work with new version of IE and then I asked what is the proper way to detect when a file has been downloaded.

My question was marked as wanting debugging help without showing code which is (what I tought was clear) not my goal. Would it have been better if I just omitted the history and went straight to the question "How can I detect a file was downloaded in javascript" ?

Comment: As [one commenter said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910743/hiding-a-div-after-a-file-is-downloaded#comment42371031_26910743), instead of describing your code, _post_ your code, and show what's wrong.

Comment: And if you did remove all the history and just asked "How can I detect a file was downloaded in javascript?", that would be closed as "too broad".

Comment: @gunr2171 - No.  Someone capable of answering this question will be perfectly able to form a clear impression of what the old method was from the text of that question.  The problem is given quite simply **the old version was triggered by a method which is no longer called**.  A working solution would obviously have to not have the same dependency, meaning that **the old code is irrelevant to finding a solution**.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like you are going to fall victim to the community's sad habit of letting their knee-jerk reflexes trump logic and comprehension of the actual situation - such as the content of your question.

Comment: Maybe the question should be *which event in IE11 replaced the `window.onfocus` that worked in IE8?*

Comment: That is indeed what they are asking.  But is it really the OP's task to write to an audience with no reading comprehension?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see what you mean but a small code snippet that explains *this works in IE8* would help. That is not much effort and guarantees the question gets reopened.

Comment: Such an example would be irrelevant to finding a solution.  The key principle here is that there a lot of people who demand things **out of habit** without bothering to really think if those things would be helpful.  **Often these people are not in a position to answer the question anyway**.  The audience of a question is not people who can't answer it, but rather people with the knowledge to do so, and that is an audience with a much higher topical reading level.

Comment: Will you **stop** bolding stuff, I'm not deaf, I'm sitting next to you...

Comment: OK, fine. In that case what would be the advice? Do we organize a reopen squad?

Comment: I understand a bit more what happened after reading these comments. I did get a solution from WisdmLabs, which makes my question a duplicate (I wasn't searching for the right keywords). Should I delete my question?

Comment: I voted to reopen and gave it an edit. Please check if you're OK with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that a more acceptable (by which I mean, acceptable by the community at large) form of your question would be something like this (and please excuse me, I know little about web programming):

> I'm updating a system that worked with IE8 to be compatible with IE11. I rely on `window.onfocus` for certain tasks. I've done some investigation and narrowed it down to the following: In IE11, `window.onfocus` does not always seem to be called, which is breaking code that worked with IE8.
>
> My main requirement is to *<insert goal e.g. always floogle the clumberputts when the window is brought into focus>*, but I cannot seem to do this reliably in IE11.
>
> I have created a minimal, self-contained demonstration here: *<insert bare minimal code to demonstrate issue, perhaps a jsfiddle link>*. If you run this with IE8, you can see that it works correctly. If you run it with IE11, you can consistently reproduce the problem like so:
>
> 1. Remove your left shoe.
> 2. Click the button on the right.
> 3. Quack like a duck.
>
> I looked around for some other reports of similar behavior and found *<insert link>*, I tried the techniques there but the issue persisted [alternatively: I found nothing at all].
>
> Why is IE11 not calling `window.onfocus`, and what can I use as a replacement?

The key points there being to clearly state what you're looking for, *narrow down your specific problem to a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/)*, describe what you've attempted so far, and ask the question in a manner that could also help other people who are struggling with the same thing (`window.onfocus` in IE11 vs IE8) but in other contexts.

Comment: After reading this, my question writing skills just improved. Thanks!